# Show that the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers is a perfect square for infinitely many $n$.

Tags: square-numbers, pell-type-equations

Show that the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers is a perfect square for infinitely many $n$.

The question doesn't make any sense to me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$, and hence you want infinitely many $n$ for which there is an $m$ with $n^2+n=2m^2$.

Comment: ohhh. I see! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1+2+\cdots + n = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}=k^2 \to n^2+n - 2k^2 = 0 \to \triangle = 1-4(1)(-2k^2) = 1+8k^2= m^2 \to m^2-8k^2 = 1$. This is a Pell equation with initial solution $(m,k) = (3,1)$, then it has infinitely many solutions, proving the claim.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how you went from $n^2+n - 2k^2 = 0$ to   $\triangle = 1-4(1)(-2k^2)$

Comment: I treat it as a quadratic equation in variable $n$, and computed the discriminant delta $ = b^2-4ac$.

Comment: [Pell's equation always has infinitely many solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation), so you do not have to find an initial solution. Rather, you need to explain why your quadratic-formula solution $n = (−1 + m)/2$ generates infinitely many natural numbers $n$, in other words, why is $-1 + m$ divisible by $2$ for infinitely many rational $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [formula for the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), you want to find infinitely many natural numbers $n$ and $y$ such that
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = y^2,$$
which you can rearrange to
$$(2n+1)^2 - 8y^2 = 1.$$
That is [Pell's equation, which has infinitely many integer solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) for $2n+1$ and $y$.

We still need to prove that $2n+1$ is odd for infinitely many of those solutions so that there will be infinitely many solutions for which $n$ is a natural number. But $(2n+1)^2$ must be odd because $8y^2$ is even and $1$ is odd, so $2n+1$ is also odd.

Thus, the sum of the first $n$  natural numbers is a perfect square for infinitely many $n$.